# Mouseover hint for TChart series value

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am using a TChart in Delphi 7, and I want to display some bar charts. I am using the following code to set up the series values from a database query:

```
  chart1.FreeAllSeries;

  chart1.SeriesList.Clear;

  chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries.Create(Self));
  TBarSeries(chart1.Series[0]).BarStyle:=bsRectGradient;

  with query1 do
    begin
      Close;
      Execute;

      while not EoF do
        begin
          chart1.Series[0].Add(FieldAsFloat('sum_actual_days'), FieldAsString('contract_no'));
          Next;
        end;

    end;
```

Each bar (value) is now showing the label both below the bar, and in a yellow rectangle above the bar.

Instead of repeating the label value twice, I have some additional information from the query that I would like to show above the bar instead of the label (or, preferably, as a mouseover hint). Can this be done with the TChart? And how... ?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with a TChart by using the chart's OnMouseMove event. Something like this should get you started:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  SeriesIndex: Integer;
begin
  SeriesIndex := Series1.Clicked(X, Y);

  Chart1.ShowHint := SeriesIndex <> -1;

  if Chart1.ShowHint then
  begin
    query1.RecNo := SeriesIndex; { this may need to be SeriesIndex + 1 }
    Chart1.Hint := query1.FieldByName('YourFieldNameHere').AsString;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, the query that you used to populate the chart must still be open for this code to work.

Answer (score 1):

The "Mark Tips" tool provides an event to supply custom text (OnGetText event):

```
procedure TForm1.ChartTool1GetText(Sender: TMarksTipTool;
  var Text: String);
var Index : Integer;
begin
  Index:=Series1.Clicked(Chart1.GetCursorPos);

  Text:='Hello point '+IntToStr(Index);
end;
```

Comment: Standard version doesn't give access to the Tools. Pro version is required.

Answer (score 0):

There is the "Mark Tips" tool that allows you to show a hint when you move over a bar. But I'm not sure if you can modify the tip to show custom data instead of the predifined styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Panel into the Chart, and use it as a hint. With the NearestPoint tool it works very well.

[image]

First add the NearestPoint tool to the chart (Double click on the chart, select Tools / Add).

Then add a Panel to the Chart (into the Chart component) and style it according to your needs.

Then use the OnMouseMove event:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var i:integer;
    px,py:integer;

begin   
  if PtInRect(Chart1.ChartRect,Point(X,Y)) then
    begin
      i:=ChartTool1.GetNearestPoint(Series1,X,Y);
      if (Series1.XValues.Count>0) and (i<Series1.Count) and (i>=0) then
        begin
          px:=Series1.CalcXPos(i);
          py:=Series1.CalcYPos(i);
          //You can add any data here to your panel, even you can put Images to it or anything else
          Panel_Hint.Caption:=TimeToStr(Series1.XValue[i])+' • '+FloatToStrF(Series1.YValue[i],ffNumber,20,2);
          Panel_Hint.Visible:=true;
          Form1.Canvas.Font.Assign(Panel_Hint.Font);
          Panel_Hint.Width:=Form1.Canvas.TextWidth(Panel_Hint.Caption)+8;
          Panel_Hint.Left:=px-Panel_Hint.Width div 2;
          Panel_Hint.Top:=py-Panel_Hint.Height-2;
        end
      else
        Panel_Hint.Visible:=false;
    end;
end;
```

If you want, you can disable the NearestPoint tool, but we need it to easily find the corresponding point.